# How to detect when an SKSpriteNode hits another SKSpriteNode?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a game where you tilt your phone and try to keep the ball inside the boundary. I can't seem to figure out how to make the ball not go through the boundary. I have the tilt to move the ball working, but it just goes through all my boundaries and I can't seem to figure out how to make the ball stop when it comes in contact with a boundary. Here is my code:

```swift
 override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
        self.physicsBody = border

        boundary = (self.childNode(withName: "boundry") as! SKSpriteNode) //the boundary is spelled wrong

        airplane = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball image")
        airplane.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 10)
        airplane.position = CGPoint(x: -211.163, y: 367.3)
        airplane.size =  CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
        airplane.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        airplane.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        airplane.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
        airplane.physicsBody?.pinned = false

        self.addChild(airplane)

        if motionManager.isAccelerometerAvailable {
            // 2
            motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.01
            motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: .main) {
                (data, error) in
                guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                    return
                }

                // 3
                let currentX = self.airplane.position.x
                self.destX = currentX + CGFloat(data.acceleration.x * 500)
                let currentY = self.airplane.position.y
                self.destY = currentY + CGFloat(data.acceleration.y * 500)
            }
        }
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

        let action = SKAction.moveTo(x: destX, duration: 1)
        let action2 = SKAction.moveTo(y: destY, duration: 1)
        airplane.run(action)
        airplane.run(action2)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In SpriteKit things don't collide unless you give them a set of matching [`collisionBitMask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1520003-collisionbitmask).  ie `border.collisionBitMask` & `airplane.collisionBitMask` need to have at least one non zero bit in common.  Try setting both to 1 to begin with.

Comment: I added `airplane.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1
        boundary.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1` to my code, and the ball still goes through the border.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing is that you may need to add a distance constraint to airplane so that it cannot escape from the border if speed is too high.